# Modeling the position of a planet as it orbits around a star

Tags: calculus

I am trying to model the motion of a planet in the following scenario:

A planet is orbiting a star in an elliptical orbit. The star is located at one of the foci of this ellipse. The planet's motion obeys Kepler's second law.

I am looking for a reasonably accurate approximation of the planet's location on a coordinate grid as a function of the time elapsed. However, I am not quite sure how to approach this problem. It would be very helpful if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks!

(As a side note, I am only familiar with math up to a high-school level of calculus.)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. This may be an interesting question. But, have you consulted any books on mechanics? How did you run into this problem? Are you developing a computer sim? Or what else drives you? Because your question has attracted two votes to put it on hold, I want to point you at [our local guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619) - providing context in particular. I wouldn't vote to close this myself, but the site politics are a bit turbulent at the moment, and there is a risk that your question may become collateral damage.

Answer (score 1):

There is no explicit formula that gives the position of the planet as a function of time but there is an implicit one that give the time as a function of the eccentric anomaly, see for example [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion#Position_as_a_function_of_time) for a detailed explanation.

If you want to avoid solving implicit equations you can make an asymptotic expansion with the eccentricity as the small parameter.